# Push upgrades to customer orgs in salesforce for newer version

Tags: managed-package, remote-site-settings

We have remote site settings that were there in the previous version of our salesforce app. Now if for newer version if I push upgrades to all customers will those remote sites be still whitelisted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes those remote sites will be there in subscriber org.

A new package won't remove those remote site settings!

Remote site settings metadata is subscriber and developer [deleteable](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc%3Fid%3Ddesign_your_app.htm)! and not upgradable!

Hence as long as you don't delete the remote site settings metadata push upgrades should have no impact on them!

Comment: Thank you @mohith for the information. Can you also help me with this question - can I push upgrade of my newer version with new components in it?

Comment: Yes you can for push upgrades but you cannot for patch!